# update a field in a array inside another array in mongoose document

Tags: node.js, arrays, express, mongoose, subdocument

```
process = {
  num: 1,
  notes: [ 
    { sequence: 1,
      user: 199283,
      votes: [
         {_id: 113222, user: 122334, text: 'something' },
         {_id: 441122, user: 123321, text: 'other something' },
      ]}, 
    { sequence: 2,
      user: 199213,
      votes: [
         {_id: 111122, user: 121564, text: 'something2' },
         {_id: 222221, user: 126621, text: 'other something2' },
         {_id: 333333, user: 123321, text: 'other something2' }
      ]}
  ]
}
```

A need to update the field `text` with `_id` = 333333 in the sub-array votes.

I tried to use Model.findAndUpdate(). But, I found in the internet examples for update with 1 levels of arrays.

How could I use mongoose to update a field in a array inside another array in a document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding the document you can make any changes to the object and then call `.save()` on the document to make the same changes in the database. I used forEach callbacks but you can also use a library like lodash to change the text.

```
let document = await Model.find({_id:2134315})

document.notes.forEach((note)=>{
  note.votes.forEach((vote)=>{
    if(vote._id==333333) vote.text="YOUR NEW TEXT HERE"
  })
})

document.save()
```

This may not work if you are using populated references but from what you described it did not seem like it.